# How to get the design in iReports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want the below design in iReports where column is generated dynamically based on a formula.
How can this be done? Please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list component` to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i am new to iReport so can u just let me know more about List component, majorly as to how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the `crosstab` component.

The crosstab allows you to set a data source for printing the columns.

The problem is, I don't know (and maybe it is not possible) to dynamically adjust the column with. If the number of columns varies in size your report will not have always the same layout.

Comment: @Shaireen You can view sample in *%JASPERREPORTS%\demo\samples\crosstabs* from **JasperReports Library** [distribution package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%204.5.0/)